# Permission to the camera breaks access to the gallery [Flutter] [flutter_inappwebview]

Tags: flutter, dart, permissions, flutter-inappwebview, fileprovider

I have a strange problem and I can't figure out what's causing it. My application has a screen with a webview using the flutter_inappwebview package. In the future, I will need access to the camera and gallery to select photos.
For the camera, I request permission via permission_handler and it works fine, but when I try to pick photos from the gallery, the application crashes with the error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority com.example.webapp.flutter_inappwebview.fileprovider`.

Code:

```
`class _WebViewPageState extends State<WebViewPage> {
  late final InAppWebViewController _webViewController;

  Future<bool> _onGoBack() async {
    if (await _webViewController.canGoBack()) {
      _webViewController.goBack();
    }
    return false;
  }

  Future<void> _permissionsRequest() async {
    await [
      Permission.camera,
      Permission.storage,
    ].request();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _permissionsRequest();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: _onGoBack,
          child: InAppWebView(
            onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
              _webViewController = controller;
            },
            initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
              url: Uri.parse(widget.mainWebViewLink),
            ),
            initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
              crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true,
                javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically: true,
                mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: false,
              ),
            ),
            androidOnPermissionRequest: (_, origin, resources) async {
              return PermissionRequestResponse(
                resources: resources,
                action: PermissionRequestResponseAction.GRANT,
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}`
```

I tried adding a fileprovider in the manifest, but that didn't work either :(. It is noteworthy that if you do not give access to the camera, the gallery opens and everything works, only in this case the camera does not work.

Comment: i dont have experience with `flutter-inappwebview`. but if you wanna try with `flutter-webview` , you can follow this steps https://medium.com/gitconnected/attach-files-images-and-videos-from-iframe-webview-in-flutter-app-effbe064e3e